# Get x amount of rows in Sequence order

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table Calling "TableAvailable" TableID as int and Available as smallInt (0,1) like this

```
TableID |Available 
1       |1
2       |0
3       |0
4       |1
5       |1
6       |1
7       |0
8       |1
```

i need a sql which i can select the 1st 3 table which is together, in our example it should be 4,5,6  which is the 1st 3 rows what is available together

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  And, are the ids in the first columns alway in a row with no gaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all groups of consecutive ids by using:

```
select min(tableid), max(tableid)
from (select ta.*,
             (row_number() over (order by tableid) -
              row_number() over (partition by available order by tableid)
             ) as grp
      from tableavailable ta
     ) ta
where available = 1
group by grp;
```

Then, adding `having count(*) >= 3 order by min(tableid)` will get the first.

However, a faster method is to just look at the availability of the next two records.  In SQL Server 2012+, you would use `lead()`:

```
select top 1 tableid_1, tableid_2, tableid_3
from (select ta.*,
             lead(available) over (order by tableid) as available_1,
             lead(available, 2) over (order by tableid) as available_2,
             lead(tableid) over (order by tableid) as tableid_1,
             lead(tableid, 2) over (order by tableid) as tableid_2,
      from tableavailable ta
     ) ta
where available = 1 and available_1 = 1 and available_2 = 1
order by tableid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would only ever need to do this for 3 and assuming tableId's are sequential with no gaps... both are probably bad assumptions...

```
SELECT Top 1 A.TableID, B.TableID, C.TableId
FROM TableAvailable A
LEFT JOIN tableAvailable B
 on A.ID = B.ID+1
LEFT JOIn tableAvailable C
 on A.ID = B.ID+2
WHERE A.Available = 1 and B.Availabe=1 and C.Available=1
order by tableID asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the format of the output, so I assumed you want rows from the table. Here is a possible solution:

```
WITH answer AS (
select MIN(TableID) as found
from TableAvailable as T1
where Available = 1
and 1 = (select Available
         from TableAvailable as T2
         where T2.TableID = T1.TableID + 1
         )
and 1 = (select Available
         from TableAvailable as T3
         where T3.TableID = T1.TableID + 2
         )         
  )
select *
from TableAvailable
join answer 
on TableID = found
or TableID = found + 1
or TableID = found + 2
```

In a working fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06a74/2